# Proof using double counting to show equality

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

How to prove using double counting that the number of ways of choosing 5 elements from 4 types is equal to the number of ways of choosing 3 elements from 6 types.

I see that this is the case but don't know how to formally prove this using double counting. Could someone give an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You want to count the number of nonnegative integer solutions to two equations:
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 &= 5\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 &= 3
\end{align}

Apply [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), and interchange the roles of stars and bars:
$$\binom{5+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{8}{3}=\binom{8}{5}=\binom{3+6-1}{6-1}$$